# How to use COUNT() in more that one column?

Tags: t-sql

Let's say I have this 3 tables

```
Countries               ProvOrStates             MajorCities                   

-----+-------------     -----+-----------      -----+-------------
 Id  | CountryName       Id  | CId | Name       Id  | POSId | Name
-----+-------------     -----+-----------      -----+-------------
 1   | USA               1   | 1   | NY         1   |  1    | NYC
```

How do you get something like

```
 ---------------------------------------------
  CountryName | ProvinceOrState | MajorCities
              |   (Count)       |   (Count)
 ---------------------------------------------
    USA       |  50             | 200
 ---------------------------------------------
   Canada     | 10              | 57
```

So far, the way I see it:

- Run the first **SELECT COUNT** (*GROUP BY Countries.Id*) on **Countries** JOIN **ProvOrStates**,
- store the result in a table variable,
- Run the second **SELECT COUNT** (*GROUP BY Countries.Id*) on **ProvOrStates** JOIN **MajorCities**,
- Update the table variable based on the  Countries.Id
- Join the table variable with Countries table ON Countries.Id = Id of the table variable.

Is there a possibility to run just one query instead of multiple intermediary queries? I don't know if it's even feasible as I've tried with no luck.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Join them all up and SELECT COUNTRY, COUNT(DISTINCT  PROVINCE), COUNT(DISTINCT CITY) GROUP BY COUNTRY

Comment: Your solution worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer comes from @lotzInSpace.

```
SELECT ct.[CountryName], COUNT(DISTINCT p.[Id]), COUNT(DISTINCT c.[Id])
FROM dbo.[Countries] ct
LEFT JOIN dbo.[Provinces] p
ON ct.[Id] = p.[CountryId]
LEFT JOIN dbo.[Cities] c
ON p.[Id] = c.[ProvinceId]
GROUP BY ct.[CountryName]
```

It's working. I'm using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` because, if a country doesn't have provinces, or a province doesn't have cities, then that country or province doesn't display.

Thanks again @lotzInSpace.

Comment: My pleasure. If I wasn't using a tablet I'd have given you this complete answer myself. Too much typing though :)

Answer (score 0):

Use sub query or derived tables and views

Basically  If You You Have 3 Tables

```
select * from [TableOne] as T1
join
(
  select T2.Column, T3.Column
  from [TableTwo] as T2
  join [TableThree] as T3
  on T2.CondtionColumn = T3.CondtionColumn
) AS DerivedTable
on T1.DepName = DerivedTable.DepName
```

And when you are 100% percent sure it's working you can create a view that contains your three tables join and call it when ever you want

PS: in case of any identical column names or when you get this message 
"The column 'ColumnName' was specified multiple times for 'Table'. "
You can use alias to solve this problem

Comment: And where is the count?

Comment: You Can Easily Run Your Count Or Any Other Aggregate Or Grouping Function On This View ...The Reason I Didn't Put It Inside The View Is To Make The View Available For Any Other Function You May Want To Use On It Later

Comment: This helped me display all the columns I wanted in one run. However, I still don't see how I'd use something like `SELECT col1, COUNT(col2), COUNT(col3) FROM ...`.

Comment: Try Accessing col2 By Using MyViewName.col2 and 
COUNT(MyViewName.col2)