# Mysql 3 tables, multiple counts grouped by, but gets stuck

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, query-performance

I'm running with some troubles on a query. I'm trying to retrieve some data of a big database where 3 tables are involved.

These tables contain data about adds where, in a backend website, the administrator can manage which local adds he wants to be displayed, position and etc... These are organized in 3 tables, 1 of them, contains all the data that are relevant to adds info (Name, date of avaliability, date of expiration, etc...). Then, there's another 2 tables which contain some extra info, but just about views, or clicks.

So I have only 15 adds, that have multiple clicks and multiple views.
Each click and view table, register a new row for every click. So, when a click is registered, it will add a new row where addid_views is a register(click), and addid is addid from adds_table. So for instance, add (1) will have 2 views and 2 clicks while add (2) will have 1 view and 1 click.

My idea is to get for each add, how many clicks and views had in total.

I have 3 tables like these:

```
         adds_table           adds_clicks_table        adds_views_table
    +-------+-----------+   +-------------+------+     +-------------+------+  
    | addid | name      |   | addid_click |addid |     | addid_views |addid |
    +-------+-----------+   +-------------+------+     +-------------+------+
    | 1     | add_name1 |   | 1           | 1    |     | 1           | 1    |
    +-------+-----------+   +-------------+------+     +-------------+------+
    | 2     | add_name2 |   | 2           | 2    |     | 2           | 1    |
    +-------+-----------+
    | 3     | add_name3 |   | 3           | 1    |     | 3           | 2    |
    +-------+-----------+   +-------------+------+     +-------------+------+


CREATE TABLE `bwm_adds` (
  `addid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`addid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `bwm_adds_clicks` (
  `add_clickid` int(19) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `addid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`add_clickid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3374 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `bwm_adds_views` (
  `add_viewsid` int(19) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `addid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`add_viewsid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2078738 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**The result would be a single table where I retrieved, per each add (addid), how many clicks and how many views it had.**

I need to get all a query where I get something like this:

```
+-------+---------+-----------+
| addid | clicks  | views     |
+-------+---------+-----------+
| 1     | 123123  | 235457568 |
+-------+---------+-----------+
| 2     | 5124123 | 435345234 |
+-------+---------+-----------+
| 3     | 123541  | 453563623 |
+-------+---------+-----------+
```

I tried to execute a query but it get's stuck and loading for undefined time... I 'm pretty sure that my query is failing cause if I remove one of the counts, displays some data very fast.

```
SELECT a.addid, COUNT(ac.addid_clicks) as 'clicks', COUNT(av.addid_views) as 'views'
        FROM `adds_table` a 
        LEFT JOIN `adds_clicks_table` ac ON a.addid = ac.addid_click
        LEFT JOIN `adds_views_table` av ON ac.addid_click = av.addid_views
                GROUP BY a.addid
```

Mysql gets loading all the time, any idea to help know what I'm missing?

**By the way**, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598229/how-to-use-count-in-more-that-one-column) where treats almost the same problem I have, you can see I have the query very similar to the first answer, but I get the Loading message all the time. No errors, just Loading.

**Edit:** I missplaced the numbers and got confused. Now the tables are fixed and I added some explanation about it.

**Edit2:** I updated the post with SHOW CREATE TABLES DEFINITIONS.

**Edit3:** Is there any way to optimise this query? It seems it retrieves the result I want but the mysql database cancels the query because it gets more than 30 seconds to execute.

```
SELECT a.addid,
       (SELECT COUNT(addid) FROM add_clicks where addid =  a.addid) as clicks,
       (SELECT COUNT(addid) FROM add_views  where addid =  a.addid) as views
    FROM adds a ORDER BY a.addid;
```

Comment: You have not provided enough information for us to help you. Please [read this note about asking good SQL questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/), and pay attention to the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question.

Comment: Sorry, I confused my self doing the tables. I hope now it's more comprehensible.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  (One improvement to your query will perform poorly in older versions.)

Comment: We still need to see your table definitions with indexes to help you.

Comment: Using Mysql 5.6.38. I'll update the post with the 3 CREATE TABLE definitions.

Comment: (Added ellipsis to indicate more columns exist.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended with a solution to my problem. The table I was trying to reach was too big cause of the bad engineered database, where in adds_views_table, for each view, a new row would be added. Ending with almost 3 millions of rows and with a table that weights almost the 35% of the entire database (326MB).

When phpmyadmin tried to execute a query, loaded for ever and never showed a result because a timeout limit applied to mysql. Changing this value would help but wasn't viable to retrieve that data and display it on a website (that implies the website or data wouldn't load until the query its executed).

That problem was fixed thanks to creating an index of addid in adds_table. Also, the query it's faster if subquery's are used for some reason. The query ended like this:

```
SELECT a.addid,
(SELECT COUNT(addid) FROM adds_clicks_table WHERE addid = a.addid) AS 'clicks',(SELECT COUNT(addid) FROM adds_views_table WHERE addid = a.addid) AS 'views'
FROM adds_table a
ORDER BY a.addid;
```

**Thanks to [@Rick James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766831/rick-james) who posted a similar query and I ended modifying it to get the data I needed**

*forgive my horrible english*

Answer (score 1):

If those are really your tables (one column, plus an auto_inc), then there is no meaningful information justifying having 3 tables instead of 1:

```
CREATE TABLE `bwm_adds` (
  `addid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  clicks INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  views  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`addid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and then `UPDATE ... SET views = views + 1` (etc) rather than inserting into the other tables.

Comment: Rick, I simplified the 3 of them to ignore irrelevant metadata inserted. Things like erased parameters, dates and other stuff irrelevant to my querys. Neither of them contain foreign keys and all I've shown it's the needed to get a query. I do agree that this database it's wrong builded and I'd have done all in one table, but since this already a big project with a huge database and it's built like this, changing the database with other structure (even if it's just one table).

Comment: @LukeMarks - It is often wise (for performance) to keep frequently updated things (like Likes and Views) separate from the main information about the item.

Comment: I just realised how bad written was that paragraph. What I wanted to say, was that the database it's already built and a big website it's using it on different files... maybe hundreds. Changing the database would imply to get everything working again and rebuild the backend. That would result in a loss of time. Maybe if the owner wants to renew the website I'll clean up and do better.

Also, I agree with you, sorry for my english again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an old version,

```
        SELECT  a.addid, 
                ( SELECT  COUNT(addid_clicks)
                    FROM  `adds_clicks_table`
                    WHERE  addid = a.addid 
                ) AS 'clicks', 
                ( SELECT  COUNT(addid_clicks)
                    FROM  `adds_views_table`
                    WHERE  addid = a.addid 
                ) AS 'views'
            FROM  adds_table AS a
```

For 5.6 and later, this might be faster:

```
SELECT  a.addid, c.clicks, v.views
    FROM  `adds_table` a
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT addid, COUNT(addid_clicks) FROM addid_clicks ) AS c USING(addid)
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT addid, COUNT(addid_views)  FROM addid_views )  AS v USING(addid)
```

If you get `NULLs` but prefer `0s`, then wrap the value in `IFNULL(..., 0)`.

If you need to discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: `...id, COUNT(addid_clicks) clicks FROM addid...` ? Summary subqueries probably need aliases.

Comment: @O.Jones - Simple rule:  In a subquery, any un-aliased names are assumed to belong to the table in the subquery.  Following this rule helps make it easy to see whether it is "correlated" or not.

Comment: I tried your query on my database. That's not what I want exactly. I need to get, per each add, how many views and clicks had **THAT ADD**. So it would end like

add1   clicks = 120   views = 123
add2   clicks = 1241 views = 12412
add3   clicks = 64     views = 7456

With yours I get all the addsid but on the first one all views and clicks in total, the rest is null.